# Best way to convert a laptop into a desktop

Tags: laptop, conversion, desktop

What is the best way to convert a laptop into a desktop? I don't want to just take the laptop, add an external screen mouse and keyboard, I want to do more. I want to be able to take the laptop and put it off to the side like you would a desktop. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

With some more info (most especially the model of your laptop) you may be interested in a [docking station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docking_station). This provides you a place to plug your laptop in with a number of ports, generally several USB for peripherals, a few video outputs for one or several monitors, and usually an audio 1/8'' jack. You can keep all these i/o devices plugged into the dock and simply connect the laptop and suddenly it is essentially the same configuration as any desktop.